# why globals() changed size during iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, interpolation

If use following code to print `globals()` key value pairs one by one:

```
for k, v in globals().items():
    # dict(globals()) working
    print(k, v)
```

will get such runtime error:

> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

I know `dict(globals())` can freeze the dict, so no issue.

But I'm a little curious what actually changed during iteration? Is the exectuing function it self?

Comment: You're creating new global variables called `k` and `v`, which means you're altering `globals()`. If you create them *before* your loop, you won't get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `global().items()`, the `items` function creates a pair with iterators which are named `k` and `v`, that's the reason python says that `dictionary changed size during iteration`.

Here's an example proof:

```
>>> globals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>}
>>> for k, v in globals().items():
    pass

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    for k, v in globals().items():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
>>> globals()
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'k': '__name__', 'v': '__main__'}
>>>
```

Notice that after the error when I call `globals()` again it contains 2 more values.